# Jakob Bernoulli’s solution

Tags: calculus, geometry

I'm reading [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brachistochrone_curve#Jakob_Bernoulli.27s_solution).

It says,

from $ds^2 = dx^2 + dy^2$, we can get

$2dsd^2s =2dxd^2x $

I cannot understand this process.
 
Please give me some references.(simpler is better)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one feels uncomfortable with differentials it is possible to explain with ordinary derivatives.

Let's divide $ds^2 = dx^2 + dy^2$ by $dy^2$ to get
$$
\left(\frac{ds}{dy}\right)^2=\left(\frac{dx}{dy}\right)^2+1\qquad\Leftrightarrow\qquad (s'(y))^2=(x'(y))^2+1.
$$
Now differentiate both sides w.r.t. $y$ using the chain rule
$$
2s'\cdot s''=2x'\cdot x''\qquad\Leftrightarrow\qquad 2\frac{ds}{dy}\frac{d^2s}{dy^2}=2\frac{dx}{dy}\frac{d^2x}{dy^2}.
$$
Multiplying by the denominator we obtain $2ds\cdot d^2s=2dx\cdot d^2x$

Answer (score 2):

It is just the chain rule with fixed $dy$, i.e $d (ds^2) = 2 ds \times d(ds) = 2 \hspace{2pt} ds \hspace{2pt} d^2 s$.

Similar for $dx$, and $d(dy) = 0$ as $dy$ is fixed.

Comment: forgive my ignorance but can you tell me wrt to which which variable they are differentiated ?

Comment: Here $d$ just means a small change in, they aren't being differentiated wrt to any variable (otherwise how would we know what $dx$ is, for example).

Comment: Oh that means the resultant statement means change of change ?

Comment: Yeh - think of acceleration for example

Comment: Thanks. last thing, When in calculus we learn these ? differential equation course ?

Comment: I can't remember explicitly being taught this, to be honest - it stems directly from the limit definition of derivatives

Comment: +1; Thanks for helping me, not many people on this site reply when asked questions on their answer by someone else.

Comment: No problem at all!